# How to create a staggering List from a List

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Suppose we have a list:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

For a given length, say `3`, I would like to create a list of Lists which contains:

```
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[3,4,5]
...
```

The number of elements in the sublist is the specified length (3).

I know how to do it in plan Java:

```
List<List<Integer>> function(List<Integer> s, int m) {
    if(s.size() < m) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size() - m + 1 ; i ++) {
        List<Integer> sub = s.subList(i, i+m);
        result.add(sub);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I would like to know how I can do it using Java 8 stream.

Can someone help?

Comment: _"I know how to do it in plan Java"_ Please show that code

Comment: The plan java code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I worked out like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> function(List<Integer> s, int m) {
     return IntStream.range(0, s.size() - m + 1).mapToObj(index -> s.subList(index, index + m)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

My test shows it is correct. But is there a better solution?